# is it ok for another app to be able to quit my app?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, jack, hig

I'm implementing support for JACK (http://www.crudebyte.com/jack-ios/) in my app (http://audulus.com if you're curious).

The JACK app has UI to quit other apps (such as mine) that are connected to it. When I receive the notification from JACK, I'm supposed to quit my app programmatically.

Should JACK instead have UI for disconnecting an app, rather than quitting it?

Relevant information:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html see "Don't Quit Programmatically"

Comment: are you implementing support in a JACK library or framework that other apps and developers can take advantage of, or are you only implementing this for your own application?

Comment: are you going to try to publish this to App Store? If so I dont think you can do that.

Comment: @SpaceDust, FWIW, apps using JACK and presumably having this recommended behavior are already in the app store.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I'm using the JACK framework provided: http://www.crudebyte.com/jack-ios/sdk/

Answer (score 2):

`abort()` is not strictly *illegal*: Apple's reviewers scan your code for prohibited API calls and `abort()` is not among them, speaking from experience. Also consider the language of the QA you link: it speaks only of "discouraging" and "recommending" against the use of `exit()` and `abort()`.

Along those lines, that QA, and the HIG, seem to suggest that the use of `exit()`/`abort()` would be improper when it makes for a poor user experience: "put users in control", the HIG says. But if JACK really does present a UI that clearly explains that your app will be closed, and the user chooses to close your app based on that UI, you are actually *maintaining* control by programmatically quitting the app.

That said, I don't think that's much of a benefit to the user. If you simply disconnect, your app's resources will still be reclaimed if necessary--but if your app doesn't get terminated, then it will start up faster the next time the user launches it. I'd venture that disconnecting would satisfy appearances in JACK, and the user would have check the app switcher bar to even see if you had terminated.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment on others' answers, unfortunately, but @wpearse, search in page for "JackClientKilled" and you'll find that JACK does suggest clients programmatically quit.

Comment: Good point -- the JACK app is quite clear about what its doing. But I suppose I would prefer JACK steer clear of requesting anything that could possibly be interpreted as a violation of Apple's rules. FWIW, AudioBus (the alternative to JACK), just disconnects apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not OK to quit your app programmatically. Apple's docs are quite clear:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1561.html

Comment: just search for exit(0) that page you linked. Its in their example code.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks for the pointer. Just because it's in their example code doesn't mean it's good practice :) See updated answer.